# Reference request: Gaussian branching processes

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

**(Q1)** Are there known constructions of branching **general Gaussian** processes (preferably in continuous time)? Something like branching fractional Brownian motion or OU.

Also, **(Q2)** what are the modern references on branching Brownian motion and **(Q3)** continuous time branching processes in general?

---

I want to stress that I am **not** interested in biology, compsci or other applications. I am interested in whether there are known **mathematical** results and constructions of branching Gaussian processes.

I also am **not** interested in references on branching Brownian motion *per se*, since I know a few of those. My second question is about references which are considered canonical.

Comment: a Google search gives many hits, for example [Maillard's thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.3500) from 2012, and [a whole list](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Branching+Brownian+motion+with+selection&btnG=) of more recent publications. --- perhaps you want to be a bit more specific in your question?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, I think I am quite specific. 1) I know a lot of references on branching Brownian motion, but virtually none on other Gaussian processes, 2) I don't know which references on branching Brownian motion are most modern ones

Comment: OK, I hope the references I list in the answer box are specific enough for your query.

Comment: The A.Boivier book "Gaussian Processesed on Trees" also goes into Branching Gaussian (on trees) and BBM. https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/gaussian-processes-on-trees/0CAE50CA3DA201B5737C8FBA0C60A406

Answer (score 2):

Some pointers to the literature on branching Gaussian processes:

- [Identifying gene-specific branching dynamics from single-cell data with a branching Gaussian process](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-018-1440-2)
- [Gaussian processes for identifying branching dynamics in single cell data](http://mlsb.cc/2017/abstracts/MLSB_2017_paper_18.pdf)
- [Branching Gaussian Processes with Applications to Spatiotemporal Reconstruction of 3D Trees](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04045)

And more specifically branching fractional Brownian motion or Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes:

- [Laws of Large Numbers for Supercritical Branching Gaussian Processes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06701)
- [Extremes of branching Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.05809v1)
- Ratio limit theorems for branching Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes

Comment: The first three are from biology and computer science... I am interested in mathematical papers. Thanks for the last three, I'll check them out.